# Converting RMS to Maximum Power

Tags: electrical-engineering, power, circuits, power-engineering, electronics

If I have a sinusoidal voltage signal of amplitude $V_m$ driving a resistance $R$, what is the relationship between the RMS power $P_{rms}$ and the maximum power $P_{max}$ delivered to the resistance?

[image]

I thought that $P_{max} = P_{rms} * 2$ (as $V_{m} = V_{RMS} * \sqrt{2}$), but I have seen some calculators online which say that $P_{max} = P_{rms} * \sqrt{2}$.

I would appreciate if if someone could provide a derivation and some clarification of this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as $P_{RMS}$!

We use RMS for voltage and current because, for power calculations, the peak voltages contribute much more power than the lower voltages.

For power calculations we have already taken the square of the voltage or current so we don't need to do it again to calculate the average power.

$$P = VI = \frac {V^2}R = I^2R$$

There is no such thing as $P_{RMS}$!